# System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path. CGI Deserialization

Tags: c#, cgi, iis-8, iis-10

I have an IIS CGI C# application which source code got lost, so i have decompile it, rebuild and host its new version.
After rebuilding, application crashes when trying to deserialize JSON file with settings (using System.Web.Extensions). Exception:

> Unhandled Exception: System.Exception: System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path.
>          at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.CheckIllegalCharacters(String[] str, Boolean onlyCheckExtras)
>          at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.AddPathList(FileIOPermissionAccess access, AccessControlActions control, String[] pathListOrig, Boolean checkForDuplicates, Boolean needFullPath, Boolean copyPathList)
>          at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission..ctor(FileIOPermissionAccess access, String[] pathList, Boolean checkForDuplicates, Boolean needFullPath)
>          at System.AppDomainSetup.VerifyDir(String dir, Boolean normalize)
>          at System.AppDomainSetup.get_ConfigurationFile()
>          at ibsnccgi.Options.ReadSettings()
>          at ibsnccgi.Options.ReadSettings()
>          at ibsnccgi.Program.Main(String[] args)

Code crashes at line that look like this:

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var bar = serializer.Deserialize<test>("{\"foo\":\"123\"}");
```

Application app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

UPDATE:

Further digging into problem leads me to this article:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/david.wang/2005/07/13/iis-6-prefixing-paths-with/
The problem is that IIS CGI application will run with some security mesures that will add a prefix '\\?\' to paths that application will access during its runtime.

For example:
Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().CodeBase is 'file://?/C:/IIS/ibsnccgi/CGIExample/TestCGI.exe';
After replacing all wrong characters it will be '\\?\C:\IIS\ibsnccgi\CGIExample\TestCGI.exe';
But '\\?\' is not a valid part of windows path, so it throw System.ArgumentException.

My solution was to move to ASP.NET application with reference to old project.

Comment: There is no `path` specified in the code you have marked as causing that exception. Is that the actual code? It seems more like you have an invalid path specified for your configuration file? And if so, what does the app.config have to do with it?

Comment: It's also not clear to me why there are tags for `cgi`, `iis-8` and `iis-10`

Comment: Because there is no path. Example code in any part of the application will cause this exception.    
Its CGI aplication hosted in IIS. I have IIS8 on server and IIS10 on local computer. On both it crashes similary.

Comment: CGI? Serious? Why cannot you simply use ASP.NET?

Comment: Here is a example code that will trigger a crash.

https://gist.github.com/rincew1nd/497328d6b5fd6f864c703739c85cb2eb